# What is the best practice for storing and processing images and videos?

Tags: c#, wpf, video-capture

My application (written in WPF/C#) will monitor a live video source and will need to store small video segments and image stills. I'm hesitant to use a user defined "temp" directory since this would potentially allow a user to modify or delete these files causing major issues with my application. Alternatively, I have attempted to store these items in memory (BitmapSource object for the images) but cannot find an equivalent object for video. Should I byte the bullet and use a temp directory and simply use the image's URI or is their a better approach? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you use the appdata store rather than a user-elected store?

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

Comment: After initially pursuing the Isolated Storage approach for a few hours, I concluded that it is not practical to use Isolated Storage for storing large video files that need to be later referenced by a Uri. As a result, I have implemented Oli's suggestion and it seems to be working nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want to look at [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx) provided by .NET

That should do the job I think..

Answer (score 0):

What we do.. 
Ideally, we store the images on a sercure remote server(like a dvr).
when this is not possible. an encyption alog.. is used to store (save and load) the images to prevent any tampering.

--
Michael