# Is it possible to reference a file stored in Isolated Storage by its URI?

Tags: c#, wpf, isolatedstorage

Using this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458307/what-is-the-best-practice-for-storing-and-processing-images-and-videos) as motivation, I would like to temporarily store images and videos in Isolated Storage. My application (written in WPF/C#) will allow a user to review these temporarily stored items by viewing their contents in a [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx). I was hoping to set the MediaElement's [Source Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.source.aspx) to a video or image's URI stored in IsolatedStorage but I cannot figure out how to dynamically create a URI since it doesn't appear to be naively supported by IsolatedStorage. Any help would be greatly appreciated - thank you in advance!

**Update - 1/21/09**
After battling the issue for a day, I concluded that the Isolated Storage approach is not practical for storing large video files that need to be referenced by a Uri.

Comment: Did you conclude that this is not possible? Or just not practical for your needs?

Comment: It would be really nice if this could be done. It would make it much simpler to display images within the app that are stored within isolated storage.

Answer (score 1):

Isolated Storage is intended to provide a way for you to store data on the client WITHOUT knowing the specific location of the files you have stored.  The reason for the lack of a URI is to keep the files you have stored in a "security sandbox".  You may be able to figure out a way to get the actual URI but if there is a way it is likely that Microsoft will release a security patch that breaks your code.

I would find a different way to accomplish your task.  It is generally a bad idea to try "fighting" the security settings in the platform since future platform changes could break your application.

Comment: +1 That's the first definite answer I found on the topic of getting an URI for a file in Isolated Storage.

Comment: -1 Just FYI, this is completely false.
Getting Uri's to files in Isolated Storage is supported, and in fact, the only other way to have an absolute Uri to an image for a FlipCycleTile other than through a hyperlink.

Comment: See this page, for example.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149026/creating-cycletile-with-remote-images