# ShellTile not updating data on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I want to schedule multiple Tile Notifications while my app is running, so that when my app is in background, my schedule Tile notifications appear one by one using respective occurrence time.
But somehow when I schedule multiple (3) notifications only last one appears.

```
String message = "";
String key = "FamilyFarm" + count;
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(duration) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) 
    return;
IsolatedStorageSettings setting = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
if (setting.Contains(key))
{
    setting.Remove(key);
}
setting.Add(key, name);
count++;

ShellTileSchedule SampleTileSchedule = new ShellTileSchedule();
bool TileScheduleRunning = false;

// Update will happen one time.
SampleTileSchedule.Recurrence = UpdateRecurrence.Onetime;

// Start the update schedule now. 
SampleTileSchedule.StartTime = DateTime.Now;

SampleTileSchedule.RemoteImageUri = new Uri(@"http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/graphical/images/conus/MaxT1_conus.png");
SampleTileSchedule.Start();
TileScheduleRunning = true;

ShellTile oTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x =>    x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("flip".ToString()));

if (oTile != null && oTile.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("flip"))
{
    FlipTileData oFliptile = new FlipTileData();
    oFliptile.Title = name;
    oFliptile.Count = 11;
    oFliptile.BackTitle = key;

    oFliptile.BackContent = name;
    oFliptile.WideBackContent = name;

    oFliptile.SmallBackgroundImage = new Uri("Assets/Tiles/FlipCycleTileMedium.png", UriKind.Relative);
    oFliptile.BackgroundImage = new Uri("Assets/Tiles/FlipCycleTileLarge.png", UriKind.Relative);
    oFliptile.WideBackgroundImage = new Uri("Assets/Tiles/Flip/FlipCycleTileLarge.png", UriKind.Relative);

    oFliptile.BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/FlipCycleTileMedium.png", UriKind.Relative);
    oFliptile.WideBackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/FlipCycleTileMedium.png", UriKind.Relative);
    oTile.Update(oFliptile);
    // MessageBox.Show("Flip Tile Data successfully update.");
    //return true;
}
else
{
    // once it is created flip tile
    Uri tileUri = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?tile=flip", UriKind.Relative);
    ShellTileData tileData =  new FlipTileData()
    {
        Title = "Hello FamilyFarm",
        BackTitle = key,
        BackContent = name,
        WideBackContent = name,
        Count = 8,
        SmallBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/FlipCycleTileMedium.png", UriKind.Relative),
        BackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/FlipCycleTileMedium.png", UriKind.Relative),
        WideBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/FlipCycleTileMedium.png", UriKind.Relative),
    };
    ShellTile.Create(tileUri, tileData, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see the Tile Cycle, you should use

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207036(v=vs.105).aspx

or

[Creating CycleTile with remote images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149026/creating-cycletile-with-remote-images)

Otherwise if you want to see the Update taking place you should put a `Thread.Sleep` or `Task.Wait` between updates to be able to see them.

When you want some cycling in WP7.8 you can use MangoPollo.

Comment: I want to change the content and title properties of the tile in a cycle in windows phone 7.

Comment: Can you help me to find any way to show shell tile with multiple messages on it for winodws phone 8.